# pytz.all_timezones returns empty list when executed from the app

Tags: python, django, pytz

I am trying to get the timezones by using pytz in my app. However the call to pytz.all_timezones always return an empty list.

```
import pytz
print pytz.all_timezones
```

I have included pytz-2011n-py2.6.egg in sys.path in apache_django.wsgi file too.

I tried with the same code in python command line and able to retireve the data. Am struck up with this issue for couple of hours.

I tried with other method country_names in pytz and it throws error

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:Python\\\\Lib\\\\site-packages\\\\pytz-2011n-py2.6.egg\\\\pytz\\\\zoneinfo\\\\iso3166.tab
```

Comment: what is output of `pytz.__file__`? pytz checks tz resources relative to its own path

Comment: alko, it returns <python home>\\Lib\\site-packages\\pytz-2011n-py2.6.egg\\pytz\\__init__.py    I checked with command line and that too returns the same

Comment: was wrong about pytz, it can be run from egg, and open_resource uses pkg_resource. so it seem your egg lacks timezones (folder `zoneinfo`)

Comment: alko, if the problem is with egg file, the result in the python command line too would result in empty list. But with command line i am able to get with same path as i used with my app

Comment: am I misunderstandin `call to pytz.all_timezones always return an empty list` followed by some code? do you get your tzones in console?

Comment: yes alko, it returns list of all timezones in console. I pasting part of content that i copied from console  >>> print pytz.all_timezones
['Africa/Abidjan', 'Africa/Accra', 'Africa/Addis_Ababa', 'Africa/Algiers', 'Africa/Asmara', 'Africa/Asmera', 'Africa/Bamako', 'Africa/Bangui', 'Africa/Banjul']

Comment: @Balachandar: your python command might use different `pytz` installation. Check that `print(pytz)` shows the same in both cases. Or zoneinfo might be inaccessible from your wsgi app. Run `strace -e open python -c'import pytz' |& grep zoneinfo` to see what files should be accessible to your script.

Comment: This is path issue in my case. I just renamed the python other than the one that is used by app and got the issue fixed.

Comment: You could post the comment as an answer. It may help others with the same issue

Answer (score 0):

For me, the problem was that pytz's dependent files were not readable.

```
sudo chmod -R +r /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pytz/
```